# How to get a collection and joins the data from the reference field?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to get collection `sales_order` and get the extra data from the reference field. This is an issue because 1 sales_order document contains several reference data.

Opiniated question: If you were me, would you try to achieve what I am trying to do or is it more `scalable` to store the `customer` data such as name inside the `sales_order` document to avoid excessive querying?

[image: Relationship between the Sales Order's collection and Customer's collection]

Expected response of `doc.data()`:

```
{
  timestamp,
  expectedDate,
  customer_id: {name, email, street, city, zip, phone}
  user_id, // similar to custoer_id
  refund_policy_id, // similar to customer_id
}
```

Actual response of `doc.data()`

```
{
  timestamp,
  expectedDate,
  customer_id: {_converter, _firestore, _path}
  user_id, // similar to custoer_id
  refund_policy_id, // similar to customer_id
}
```

I use cloud functions which is unrelated to this issue, this is the basic code I use to query collection `sales_order`.

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("sales_order")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    let array = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      array.push(doc.data());
    });

    return array;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `Customer` a subcollection of `sales_order` in your Firestore Structure? Could you share your firestore structure (It can be a screenshoot) instead of a ERD for a better representation of what you DB actually looks like?

Comment: Hi, opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Rephrase your question to ask something objective (see the [help] for more info), or you risk your question getting closed/eventually deleted.

Comment: @RafaelLemos https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOt5J.png I hope this helps, I am currently building the Firestore Structure, it's not complete.

Comment: @RafaelLemos  I do found simple way to get the data `doc.data().customer_id.get().then(doc => doc.data())`. This will cause the app to read the DB 2 times. I will refactor the code, hopefully to find a way, one with only 1 DB read instead of 2 DB read.

Comment: @TylerH I appreciate your concern. Please kindly edit the question as you see fit. However, I do wish someone would share their insight regarding the Firestore Structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have this structure per what you shared:

```
sales_order Collection
    id
    customer_id
    refund_policy_id
    timestamp
    expectedDate
    
Customer Collection
    id
    name
    ...
    phone
```

With this structure you will have to make 2 reads for every `sales_oder` document if you want the `Customer` Collection data, however, the advantage of this approach is that if you have to update the `Customer` data you don't have to make 1 extra write per `sales_order` done by that `Customer` to keep the data updated.

An approach that would get everything in 1 read, is the following, where you keep a copy of the `customer` document inside an object on your `sales_order` document:

```
sales_order Collection
    id
    customer : {
        CustomerId
        name
        ...
        phone
    }
    refund_policy_id
    timestamp
    expectedDate

Customer Collection
    id
    name
    ...
    phone
```

Since Firestore allows you to make replicate data as much as you want this is a viable approach, and you can perform only 1 read to achieve your immediate objective, however, you will have to make 1 extra write per `sales_order` made by a `customer` once you have to update `customer` data.

So basically it depends on what/how you want to get the `customer` data. Personally I would go with the first approach, due to of the ease of data maintenance in case of an update of `customer` data, because if he has many `sales_order` it could get out of hand quite easily, plus it makes for a simpler code.

**NOTE**: I focuses on `sales_order` and `customer` collections, but the same applies to `refund policy`.

Let me know if you have any more question on this.